# How to call a function inside a django html template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django. The question is rather basic and I read some google links and documents, apparently I can't resolve it.

Basically:

I need to access the blog entries of a particular blog inside html file, but apparently blog.blogentry_set() is not working as expected. Could someone help please. Here is the code I tried:

models.py file:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
   subject = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
   ...

class BlogEntry(models.Model):
   ref = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
   ...
```

index.html file:

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
    <p>{{ blog.subject}}</p>
    <div>
      <p>{{blog.date}}</p>
      {% for entry in blog.blogentry_set.all() %}
          {{entry.text}}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to delete (), and this helps to take off the error message, but the entry text is not printed as expected, so something is again not working.

I heard in template language, to call function we do not need (), but then how do we pass arguments?

also, I am asking to myself: do I need to 'load' some file here? Please help :D

Comment: Tried removing the parenthesis?

Comment: yeah, but then there is nothing happenning

Comment: one weird thing is that even calling {{Blog.objects.count}} does not print anything

Comment: What's in the view that serve this request?

Comment: Are you sure your query brings any result?

Comment: @J0HN you mean the function call? it's def index(request)

Comment: @jweyrich yeah, because blog.date and blog.subject properly print the correct results

Comment: If you put other random print inside the inner loop it works?

Comment: yeah, it works. guys, can you tell me how to call an external function as well? is it using "load"?

Comment: You have to create a template tag, or pass the function's result via context to the template.

Answer (score 6):

You can't pass an argument to a callable attribute like this. Either pull the value in the view, or write a custom template tag to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To address the first problem (*"`blog.blogentry_set()` is not working as expected"*), remove the parenthesis after the `.all` like:

```
{% for entry in blog.blogentry_set.all %}
    {{entry.text}}
{% endfor %}
```

The second issue (*"to call function we do not need (), but then how do we pass arguments?"*), is amply addressed by @Varnan K's answer. You will likely have to create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).